# How can I automatically modify a database record after a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, django, cron

I am writing a web app with the Django framework, and I have some higher level questions about how I would automatically modify my data after certain time periods.

I have two different updates that I want to do:

1. I want to perform some actions on my database every Monday at 12:01 AM. I have been thinking I would just run a cron job to do this.
2. I have a model "Transaction" That has a time created field. 48 hours after a Transaction is created, I want to switch some Boolean fields in the Transaction, and make some changes to other related objects.

Is my best bet for #2 just running a cron job every minute, checking if any transactions are 48+ hours old? Is there an easier way to do both that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish these 2 things with a package called Celery.

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing.

Here's an introduction for Django users:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

For Question 1 - You can execute a Periodic Task in Celery using the crontab scheduler type:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules

For Question 2 - I would reference the following Stack Overflow question for executing a delayed task in a model:
[Django - Executing a task through celery from a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107085/django-executing-a-task-through-celery-from-a-model)

Comment: This looks great, I was really hoping to find something like this. Thanks for the awesome answer.