# Celery (4.2): how to get task id for current task

Tags: python, django, celery

## AIM

For the purposes of an alarm clock, I am attempting to 'get' the specific `Alarm` created by the `User` in the `SetAlarmForm`.

From the other answers on the same topic ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872854/getting-task-id-inside-a-celery-task), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915758/how-to-get-task-id-in-celery-django-from-the-currently-running-shared-task-itsel), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107085/django-executing-a-task-through-celery-from-a-model)), I am attempting the line: `objx = Alarm.objects.get(id=run_alarm.request.id)`. Perhaps, I am missing something obvious or the version of Celery has been updated?

## ERROR

```
[ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] raised unexpected: DoesNotExist('Alarm matching query does not exist')
```

## CODE

**Models.py**

```
class Alarm(models.Model):
    """ Model representing each Alarm """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

**Views.py**

```
class AlarmCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """ CreateView for User to create the Alarm object """
    model = Alarm
    form_class = SetAlarmForm
    template_name = 'weather_alarm/set_alarm.html'
    login_url = "/login/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.create_alarm_object(self.request, form)
        run_alarm.delay()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

**Tasks.py**

```
import time
from celery import Celery, shared_task, current_task
from datetime import datetime

from .models import Alarm


@shared_task
def run_alarm():
    """ Function to organise the steps for the alarm using Celery """
    objx = Alarm.objects.get(id=run_alarm.request.id)
    second_countdown = objx.get_alarm_length() # get the length of the alarm, in seconds
    time.sleep(second_countdown) # wait for the alarm time
    conditions_satisfied = objx.check_conditionals() # check if conditionals are satisfied
    if conditions_satisfied == True:                    # conditions are satified
        print("Ring ring!")
        return True
    else:                                               # conditions aren't satisfied
        print("I'm only sleeping!")
        return True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to fix this would be to make `alarmID` an argument passed to your task:

**Tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def run_alarm(alarmID):
    objx = Alarm.objects.get(id = alarmID)
```

You'll need to pass this ID when calling your task in your view:

**Views.py**

```
...
def form_valid(self, form):
    #making an assumption about what create_alarm_object returns here; you get the idea
    newAlarm = self.create_alarm_object(self.request, form)
    run_alarm.delay(newAlarm.id)
```

Notice how you can pass the argument to `run_alarm` by giving it to `delay` here. Further reading: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#example

The reason you are encountering your error is that `request.id` is going to point at the task ID of the individual asynchronous celery task being run, not at the ID of the alarm object. Further reading: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=request#task-request

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and referenced feedback. I tried as suggested and am getting: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'` with the exception location being `run_alarm.delay(newAlarm.id)`

Comment: Your `create_alarm_object` method isn't included in your original question, but my example was written with the assumption that this method would return the alarm object it created. It looks like it's currently returning `None` instead. You'd want to update that method to return the newly created object or its ID, then use that ID as the argument provided to the `delay` call.